# TFS 2010 Alerts Explorer

Tags: tfs, build-automation, tfsbuild, tfs-alerts

Is there a possibility to setup different alerts for different build definitions in one project? i.e. I would like to send alerts only for nigthly build but not for the CI build?. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an alert and add the attribute "StartTime" mention the start time as the nightly build starttime. I havent used this property at all and dont know the format and I couldnt find any documentation about it. You can just play around with it and would be an easy find.

The filter expression would be something like 
""TeamProject" = 'ABC' AND "DefinitionPath" = '\ABC\Test_new'  AND ("StatusCode" = 'Failed' OR "StatusCode" = 'PartiallySucceeded' OR "StatusCode" = 'Stopped' OR "StatusCode" = 'Succeeded') AND StartTime = ""

There is a request out to MS to release the documentation for these properties:
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3205145-tfs-vs2010-power-tools-alerts-explorer-documen